# PowerShell - how to determine programmatically whether StrictMode is set?

Tags: powershell, strict

I know that I can override in a script or function the StrictMode setting inherited from a higher scope. But how can I find out in a script or function what the inherited setting is?

Comment: I don't think there's any supported way to get it from the public API, reflection is the only way

Comment: Rohn Edwards ( https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-StrictMode-Get-the-900af6da ) provided an elaborate solution using reflection that is specific to Windows PowerShell. It does not work in PowerShell Core. I definitely would prefer getting the setting from PowerShell’s public API instead of a non-public field.

Comment: @wfr Rohn Edwards link is broken...  can you update the link and/or also include the name of the code solution.

Comment: Rohn Edwards addressed the StrictMode issue here: https://rohnspowershellblog.wordpress.com/2013/12/18/get-strictmode/ . As of today, the links on his blog do not take you to the code.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps a small function can help:

```
function Get-StrictMode {
    # returns the currently set StrictMode version 1, 2, 3
    # or 0 if StrictMode is off.
    try { $xyz = @(1); $null = ($null -eq $xyz[2])}
    catch { return 3 }

    try { "Not-a-Date".Year }
    catch { return 2 }

    try { $null = ($undefined -gt 1) }
    catch { return 1 }

    return 0
}

Get-StrictMode
```

Comment: Your suggestion to determine the current StrictMode setting by forcing terminating errors in try/catch blocks in sequence from most restrictive to least restrictive largely answers the question. There is just one caveat, it cannot distinguish between strict mode version “3.0” and “latest”.

Comment: @wfr Yes, there is indeed no way to test for `Latest`. AFAIK currently this is the same as version 3. However, maybe in the future, there will be another versioned strictmode. In that case we need to update the function.

Comment: It might also we worth to mention, that strict mode settings are not propagated into module scopes. Were the proposed Get-StrictMode function included in a module, it would report the setting in the module scope, which by default is equivalent to Set-StrictMode -Off.

Comment: @wfr is there no way around this? This would be a very useful function to include in my module

Comment: @Brett having read your comment I gave it some more thought but could not find a work-around.